# Enviar id via POST no Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou trabalhando em uma implementação do Datatables, mas surgiu a necessidade de enviar o id para fazer os filtros:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                responsive: false,
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
     null,
     null,
     null,     
     null
    ],    
    //"scrollY": 400,
    "scrollX": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
     url :"../php/admin_gerente_cidade.php",
     type: "post",
     error: function(){
      $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
      $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">Nenhum resultado encontrado</th></tr></tbody>');
      $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");
     }
    }
   } );
  } );
```

Se eu colocar

```html
url :"../php/admin_gerente_cidade.php?id=<?php $id; ?>"
```

Não funciona.

Seria possível passar um id via POST?

Comment: você precisa passar o data: {id: id}

Comment: Nao tenho muito conhecimento de php, mas ali onde tah o $id, como não é interpolação de string (por causa do <?php ?>, da um echo antes do $id e veja se resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta informar a propriedade `data`, segue abaixo como ficaria no seu caso, substitua `seu_id` pelo valor que você precisa.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                responsive: false,
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,                   
                    null
                ],              
                //"scrollY": 400,
                "scrollX": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 100,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"../php/admin_gerente_cidade.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {id: seu_id},
                    error: function(){
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">Nenhum resultado encontrado</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");
                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado!